# Ruby mini_racer: self is not defined

Tags: ruby, v8, embedded-v8, therubyracer

I'm trying to run [axlsign.js](https://github.com/wavesplatform/curve25519-js/blob/master/axlsign.js) from ruby using `mini_racer` gem.

```
context = MiniRacer::Context.new
context.load('axlsign.js')
context.eval('axlsign.generateKeyPair(new Uint8Array(32))')
```

It returns error 
`JavaScript at <anonymous>:1436:4: ReferenceError: self is not defined (MiniRacer::RuntimeError)`

Browser javascript console executes `axlsign.generateKeyPair(new Uint8Array(32))` without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed `self` to `this` on the very last line of the JS file and it resolved the issue.